# Issues with multiple delimiters for records and fields in a Oracle External Table

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle11g, external-tables

Given a .CSV file in the format;

```
!!"9999"!@!""!@!""!@!""!!
!!"100"!@!""!@!""!@!"INP"!!
!!"700"!@!""!@!""!@!""!!
!!"800"!@!""!@!""!@!""!!
```

STARTING and ENDING delimiter= !!
Field delimiter = !@!
All Fields surrounded by double quotes

The following EXTERNAL SYNTAX does not properly work;

```
CREATE TABLE caunit_ext 
(
 ID                 VARCHAR2(4), 
 MILL_FAC_ID        VARCHAR2(200), 
 MILL_LOC_ID        VARCHAR2(200), 
 MILL_ENC_TYP_ID    VARCHAR2(200)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY PWSTAGING
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY '!!'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '!@!'
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
         ID                 CHAR(4), 
         MILL_FAC_ID        CHAR(200), 
         MILL_LOC_ID        CHAR(200), 
         MILL_ENC_TYP_ID    CHAR(20)   
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('CAUNIT.csv')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
/

select * from caunit_ext;
```

1. Can I use multiple characters as a delimiter? Doc's I see don't say you can't, but don't say you can either!
2. Since my beginning record and ending record delimiter is the same, how to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple characters as a delimiter.

The Oracle loader documentation says that the delimiter must be a single character, but it doesn't say anything about the field delimiter.

So, you can use any number of characters for both delimiters.

For example, you could use "!!@!!" as the delimiter and "!@!" as the field delimiter.

This would work fine with the following EXTERNAL SYNTAX:

```
CREATE TABLE caunit_ext 
(
 ID                 VARCHAR2(4), 
 MILL_FAC_ID        VARCHAR2(200), 
 MILL_LOC_ID        VARCHAR2(200), 
 MILL_ENC_TYP_ID    VARCHAR2(200)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY PWSTAGING
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY '!!@!!'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '!@!'
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
         ID                 CHAR(4), 
         MILL_FAC_ID        CHAR(200), 
         MILL_LOC_ID        CHAR(200), 
         MILL_ENC_TYP_ID    CHAR(20)   
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('CAUNIT.csv')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
/

select * from caunit_ext;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me;

KUP-04021: field formatting error for field ID
KUP-04026: field too long for datatype
KUP-04101: record 1 rejected in file /mnt/systems/CAUNIT.csv

Comment: Can you try double quotes around the delimiters?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use FILLER arguments to throw away the junk;

Like

```
create table REFRESHTABLE(C1 varchar2(200), C2 varchar2(200), C3 varchar2(200), C4 varchar2(200),C5 varchar2(200), C6 varchar2(200), C7 varchar2(200), C8 varchar2(200)) 
                ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY PWSTAGING ACCESS PARAMETERS (FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''"'' MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
                    (
                         FILLER,
                         C1      CHAR(200), 
                         FILLER,
                         C2      CHAR(200), 
                         FILLER,
                         C3      CHAR(200), 
                         FILLER,
                         C4      CHAR(200),   
                         FILLER,
                         C5      CHAR(200), 
                         FILLER,
                         C6      CHAR(200), 
                         FILLER,
                         C7      CHAR(200), 
                         FILLER,
                         C8      CHAR(200)   
                    )
                  )
                  LOCATION (''' || V_CURRENTTABLE || '.csv''))';
```